# ReferenceError: list is not defined with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am getting an strange issue while trying to write to db using the following:

```
app.post('/l/create', function(req, res) {
    var text = req.body.text;
    console.log('Inside create');
    console.log(text);

    var listObj = {
        index: 0,
        name: text,
        cards: []
    };

    console.dir(listObj);

    DB.ListTable.create(listObj,
        function(err) {
            if (err) res.send(err);

            getSnippets(res);
        }
    );
});
```

Here is the error message i got:

```
C:\NodeApps\myapp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1116
    if (list.path.indexOf(lastPath) !== 0) {
        ^
ReferenceError: list is not defined
at C:\NodeApps\myapp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1116:9
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at model.Document.$__dirty 
    (C:\NodeApps\myapp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1115:7)
```

I dont get this while i run a delete on the table.

I am what might be causing this. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had been banging my head over this issue the whole day. Just removing all `node_modules` and doing `npm install` solved this problem.

I don't really understand how this could have happened, but the last change after which my app broke was installing `nodemon`.

Answer (score 0):

You were  using NODE package(nodemon) specific syntax to iterate over arraylist and node package was not installed on your machine.

You had another option to use javascript way of iterating over arrayList  Like:

```
            for (var x in summary){
                if (summary.hasOwnProperty(x)){
                console.log("-  array--"+x)
                }
```